# Can't get past log in page on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Just today I booted up my desktop PC with Windows 10 on it. As normal I get to the login screen to enter my password. I enter it and press/click enter. What happens now is that it only loads for a while on the same page (the load icon spins), and then just returns to the same page for me to enter my password again. It doesn't say my password is wrong, and I've checked that capslock is off.

Nothing happens at all, I just keep reappearing on the same login page.
I've tried starting with safe-mode and that actually works to log in with, but rebooting to normal windows and try log in again brings me the same events as earlier.

Does anyone have any clue of what to do? I am at complete loss and very desperate.

Comment: You could try and restore Windows to a previous state. Try a couple days ago or sometime you know that it worked fine. You can do a system restore from Safe Mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have not created any states. I tried restoring but found out I had none

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a corrupted Windows file. Try [SFC and DISM Windows repair utilities](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93) from Safe mode, preferably with network access, so that the scan can find replacements for bad files. See also [HowToGeeks](http://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) on these tools.

Let us know if it helps!